# Excel programming. Get current copied cells

Tags: excel, copy, range, vba

I am currently developing an AddIn where I am in the need to change some cell values when the changing cells meets certaing criteria. The problem i have is that I am losing the ability to copy a cell and paste it multiple times. I am trying to get current copied cells so I can copy then again after I change the values on the required cells.

Is there anyway I can get the current copied cells/range?

Comment: You cannot "keep" the copy selection if you do another action. But you could store the range you used, the values, and so on... Tell us a bit more if you want help (and show us your code). You can edit your question to do so.

Comment: reading your question time and again .... are you loosing the content of the clipboard buffer (with possibly one or more cells in it that you want to paste somewhere further on)? Give us more info to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a subroutine similar to this:

```
Sub Foo(rngRange as Range, rngOutputRange as Range)

    Dim varVariant as Variant
    Dim lngCounter as Long

    varVariant = rngRange  'Assuming rngRange is one column here

    For lngCounter=lBound(varVariant,1) to uBound(varVariant,1)
        If varVariant(lngCounter)=TRUE 'or whatever your criteria are
            'Do whatever you need here
        End If
    Next lngCounter

    rngOutPutRange=varVariant

End Sub
```